# Can I self update in where statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a procedure, that takes it's where statement from a column in another table. I would like to add a specific condition, only for the first execution of the statement, without adding any additional rows/tables/columns. So i thought about setting the statement to

```
tblBill.sdApprovedDate > dateadd(month,-3,getdate()) and 
(update tblInvoiceConfig 
set vcWhereSQL = 'tblBill.chBillStatus = ''A'' ' 
where intID = 7)
```

But I get an error saying update is not a bool expression.
I have 2 questions

a) can i somehow make this update a boolean expression

b) would such query execute properly (as in, the first time the condition would be date has to be no less then 3 months old, and every execution after that would only check chBillStatus)

EDIT: 
As someone asked, part of the procedure in which this value is used

```
SET @nvcSQLQuery = '
SELECT DISTINCT top 3
tblBill.intBillID, 
(... a lot of other stuff ..)
FROM 
(...)
WHERE
' + SELECT vcWhereSQL from tblInvoiceConfig where intID = 7 + '
(...)'

print @nvcSQLQuery
INSERT INTO @result
EXECUTE sp_executeSQL   @nvcSQLQuery,
                        @nvcSQLParams, 
                        @pvcArchiveType = @pvcArchiveType
```

Comment: Is this select statement

Comment: I have never seen anyone want to do something like that, and, I think the error really is telling you you cannot do that. A WHERE clause only wants  boolean expressions, as it is evaluating the data for it to be returned. What are you actually wanting to do here?

Comment: This syntax wont work

Comment: What constitutes first?

Comment: @Mihai the first time a procedure, which gets its `where` statement from column in another table, executes.

Comment: @Leonidas199x in general I was asked to make it so that the where statement of a certain procedure executes one way the first time the procedure is called, and in another way after that. The statement itself is taken from an sql table.

Comment: You need a reliable condition for the "first time" which depends solely on current db data.  Imagine Db was rolled back, what is first time now?

Comment: Can you show how do you usually make your conditions from the field "vcWhereSQL"? Is it any dynamical query?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to update the table, add your condition to query like this:

```
    SET @nvcSQLQuery = '
    SELECT DISTINCT top 3 t.intBillID
    FROM (
        SELECT
        tblBill.intBillID, 
        (... a lot of other stuff ..)
        FROM 
        (...)
        WHERE 
        tblBill.sdApprovedDate > dateadd(month,-3,getdate()) and
        tblBill.chBillStatus = ''A'' AND

        ' + SELECT vcWhereSQL from tblInvoiceConfig where intID = 7 + '
        (...)

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
        tblBill.intBillID, 
        (... a lot of other stuff ..)
        FROM 
        (...)
        WHERE 
        tblBill.sdApprovedDate <= dateadd(month,-3,getdate()) and   
        ' + SELECT vcWhereSQL from tblInvoiceConfig where intID = 7 + '
        (...)
    )t
'

    print @nvcSQLQuery
    INSERT INTO @result
    EXECUTE sp_executeSQL   @nvcSQLQuery,
                            @nvcSQLParams, 
                            @pvcArchiveType = @pvcArchiveType
```

or like this:

```
SET @nvcSQLQuery = '
    SELECT
    tblBill.intBillID, 
    (... a lot of other stuff ..)
    FROM 
    (...)
    WHERE 
    ((tblBill.sdApprovedDate > dateadd(month,-3,getdate()) and
    tblBill.chBillStatus = ''A'')
    OR tblBill.sdApprovedDate <= dateadd(month,-3,getdate()))

    AND

    ' + SELECT vcWhereSQL from tblInvoiceConfig where intID = 7 + '
    (...)
'

    print @nvcSQLQuery
    INSERT INTO @result
    EXECUTE sp_executeSQL   @nvcSQLQuery,
                            @nvcSQLParams, 
                            @pvcArchiveType = @pvcArchiveType
```